# BDD with Cypress & Vite (Vue 3) & Cucumber

Tags: vue.js, cucumber, cypress, vuejs3, vite

I've currently managed to implement Cucumber BDD tests within a Vitejs + Vue 3 as follows:

I start and run the development server with:

```
$ yarn dev
```

And then in a separate window I run the Cypress test runner:

```
$ yarn cy:run
```

Which corresponds to:

```json
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "cy:run": "cypress run -q",
    ...
  },
  ...
```

In my package.json. The output of this, is 1 test passing.

So far, so good. I then came across the `@cypress/vite-dev-server` package, and implemented it with the cucumber preprocessor inside `/cypress/plugins/index.ts` as follows:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
const path = require('path')
const { startDevServer } = require('@cypress/vite-dev-server')
const browserify = require('@cypress/browserify-preprocessor')
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
module.exports = (on: Cypress.PluginEvents, config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions) => {
  on('dev-server:start', options => {
    return startDevServer({
      options,
      viteConfig: {
        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'vite.config.ts')
      }
    })
  })

  const cucumberOptions = {
    ...browserify.defaultOptions,
    typescript: require.resolve('typescript')
  }

  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber(cucumberOptions))

  return config
}
```

So, it looks like the `@cypress/vite-dev-server` package doesn't accept what I am trying to do with Cypress & Cucumber.

Has anyone managed to get Cypress & Cucumber BDD working with Vite in a seamless fashion?

I've also looked at the `wait-on` module, running the following:

```
yarn dev & wait-on http://localhost:8099
```

But it doesn't seem to be waiting, only the Vite server runs? So I can't then run the cypress command I need ...

Comment: Hi! Same problem over here, I'm also using NX (monorepo). In my case, even though the app starts Cypress doesn't. Did you manage to find a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `@cypress/vite-dev-server` is for component testing, not e2e testing. The `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` on the other hand is for compiling e2e specs.
In e2e testing, the app runs independently from tests, so you can use `vite` for running the dev server, but it has nothing to do with tests. If you want to use `vite` config for compiling tests you can use [cypress-vite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-vite) instead of `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`.

Comment: Do you have any examples how to use cypress-vite with Cucumber?

Comment: cypress-vite cannot preprocess cucumber *.feature files by itself